# Calling javascript functions without parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

When i was reading some code of jquery then i found this in one of their widgets

```
    option: {
        _page: this._getPage,
        _panelInner: this._getPanelInner()
    },
    _getPage : function(){ //code goes here that returns something..},
    _getPanelInner : function(){ //code goes here that returns something..}
```

I wanna know how's the first `this._getPage` function is being called without parenthesis. And if functions can be called like this then why the next function `_getPanelInner` is being called with parenthesis..?

Comment: It's not called, a reference to the function is passed instead. `var a = function() {}; var b = a;` <--- here 2 variables refer to the same function.

Comment: thanks a lot..It totally solved my problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_panelInner` will hold the value *returned* by the `_getPanelInner` function while `_page` will hold a *reference* to the `_getPage` function. This means that the function would be able to be called in one of the following ways:

- `option._page()`
- `this._getPage()`

Both of these function calls would execute the same function but **that function is not called automatically (according to the code that is displayed).**

Comment: "return value of the _getPanelInner function" --- this does not sound right.

Comment: I mean the "return value" of the function, @zerkms. I'm not sure how else to phrase that...

Comment: I agree it's not easy to phrase it concisely though :-)

Comment: @zerkms '_getPanelInner' is returning an object so i think '_panelInner' is holding that object

Answer (score 3):

It's not getting called, it's only having a reference to the function so later you can do:

```
option._page();
```